how to handle web servers replying with relative web links with NGINX as reverse proxy
I am trying to connect 100's of private web-servers from public address domain using nginx as reverse proxy.
The URL i am using to connect web servers using their ip address as below.
http://172.18.157.239/192.168.20.100

172.18.157.239 is nginx server
192.168.20.100 is private web server.

The issue is private web server some of the responses sending relative path ex:- "/login.html" for which i am getting 404 NOT FOUND Error because  nginx points to http://172.18.157.239/login.html, where there is no page present.
Below is my location block in nginx.conf file.
location  ~* "/(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})" {
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_buffering off;
           client_max_body_size 1g;
           access_log off;
           proxy_pass_request_body on;
           proxy_set_header Host              $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
           proxy_pass_request_headers on;
           proxy_pass http://$1:80/;
}

I tried multiple options but not able to find the solution for this issue, can some please help on this.
Please let me know  if more details required.
